# add rowspan for datagrid

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, row, html-table

I have a datagrid and in the first column I have added a table to create rows in the datagrid. 
Is it possible for the last row to span across the datagrid?
As you can see in the image the Shipper and Desc are all in the first column. 
But can Desc continue across the other columns instead of staying the first column?

[image]

Code:

```
<asp:DataGrid  CssClass="printTableResults" runat="server" ID="gvHawb" 
                                ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false"
                                DataKeyField="ID" 
                                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                allowpaging="false">
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="printTableHeader" />
                                <Columns> 
                                    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="HAWB" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"AWBNumber") %></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><label>Shipper</label></td>
                                                    <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"FullShipperAddress") %></td>
                                                </tr> 
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><label>Desc</label></td>
                                                    <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DescriptionOfGoods") %></td>
                                                </tr>     
                                            </table>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateColumn> 
                                    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Pieces" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"TotalNoOfPieces") %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Chargeable Wt" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"TotalChgWt") %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
                            </Columns>                
                            </asp:DataGrid>
```